# Saving the Activity state in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Hello guys I've `ColorPicker` in my app. When I set the color selected by `ColorPicker` to the `Activity` background, it works. But when I restart the app, the color changes to default! How to save the state of `Activity`? Is it possible? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: considering you're quitting the application and opening it, you're supposed to store the data in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: [example question from stackowerflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: Please guys can you show me an example? I'm unable to study this code and know how to use it!

Comment: But how to make the color save? Should I post my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for example you can save the color like this (I've just put a hex color reference but you can change it to whatever you wish):

```
public void setBackgroundColor() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("color", "#FFFFFF");
    editor.commit();
}
```

Then just make sure you call this method every time it loads / reloads:

```
public void getBackgroundColor() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences.contains("color")) {
        String myColor = sharedPreferences.getString("color", null);
        mybackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(myColor));
    }
}
```

Comment: just for using methods +1

Comment: How can I put `int` instead of "#FFFFFF"?

Comment: Just change the putString and getString to putInt and getInt :)

Answer (score 2):

Andy's Answer is correct. However, I thought I would chime in on saving and loading preferences. These are universal Save/Load methods for Strings. It's what I use in all my activities. It can save you a lot of headaches in the future!

```
 public static String PREFS_NAME = "random_pref"; 

 static public boolean setPreference(Context c, String value, String key) {
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);
        settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        return editor.commit();
    }

    static public String getPreference(Context c, String key) {
        SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);
        settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME , 0);
        String value = settings.getString(key, "");
        return value;
    }
```